# When will the oneOffTaks be executed again with result GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_RESCHEDULE

Tags: android, networking, google-cloud-messaging, schedule, gcm-network-manager

So from Android SDK for GcmNetworkManager

> public static final int RESULT_RESCHEDULE
>
> Indicates a task has failed to execute, and must be retried with
>   back-off.

```
Task task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
                    .setService(MyService.class)
                    .setExecutionWindow(0, 15)
                    .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                    .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
                    .setRequiresCharging(false)
                    .build();
            mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

Inside MyService

```
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    /** task execution logic here */
    if (success) {
        return RESULT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return RESULT_RESCHEDULE;
    }
}
```

When the execution fails, it will return RESULT_RESCHEDULE, and it will be retried. So I am wondering when will it be retried?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [documentation](https://github.com/filipproch/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example/blob/master/README.md), `RESULT_RESCHEDULE` means that your task failed then reschedules your task, so it will be executed again when conditions are met.

> By default, if you return `RESULT_RESCHEDULE` from your `onRunTask`, your task is executed again as soon as conditions (charging, internet available) you defined for it are met.
>
> - one option, if you need only to limit the count of reschedules is to store somewhere the number of reschedules, and when it reaches your defined limit, return `RESULT_FAILURE` instead of `RESULT_RESCHEDULE`
> - second one, if you need more control would be to return `RESULT_FAILURE` and schedule an OneOff task, make it recognizable by some special tag and again count how many times have you scheduled it somewhere, this way you will be able to control count and delay between executions of the task

However, you may check this [tutorial](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry) when your code often fails and must be retried. Java 7/8 library provides rich and unobtrusive API with fast and scalable solution to this problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the description. I understand it better now. That library may be a bit heavy for my case, but a very good recommendation though